# C++ CMake FLANN failing when building pcl in vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vtk, point-cloud-library, flann, qhull

Trying to build PCL on VS2012 in Windows 8.1 so I can attempt to integrate my Kinect for Windows v2 sensor with it, however I seem to be running into a bunch of CMake errors that I don't know what to do with. this is partially because I am not very familiar with CMake, and so I am following the tutorial [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_dependencies_windows.php) which outlines the building of dependencies using the CMake GUI. However, throughout this process I have found that the only things that have built properly are the ones I build using cmake in the command line. the errors are:

For FLANN:

When trying to build INSTALL in VS2012 (this isn't even getting into the other build errors, but lets start here) I get:

> Error 21  error C2228: left of '.serialize' must have
>   class/struct/union    D:\flann-1.8.4-src\flann-1.8.4-src\src\cpp\flann\util\serialization.h
>   line 18:         type.serialize(ar);  Error   24  error LNK1181: cannot
>   open input file
>   '..\lib\Release\flann.lib'    D:\flann-1.8.4-src\flann-1.8.4-src\build\examples\LINK
>   Error 25  error MSB3073: The command "setlocal C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
>   -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd :cmEnd endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto
>   :cmDone :cmErrorLevel exit /b %1 :cmDone if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto
>   :VCEnd :VCEnd" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 134

For VTK:

the VTK_USE_QTOPENGL option is not appearing, even though I already first enable VTK_USE_QT, and project generation for VS2012 crashed a few times, but was able to move past the crashes (I worry that this doesn't bode well for actually using VTK)

For Qhull:

similar error as FLANN:

> Error 1   error MSB3073: The command "setlocal C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
>   -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd :cmEnd endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto
>   :cmDone :cmErrorLevel exit /b %1 :cmDone if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto
>   :VCEnd :VCEnd" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 134

but the rest of it builds nicely. any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had similar issues building PCL with VS2012 in Windows 7.

This is how I solved:
For all cases, before open **Visual studio as administrator**.

**FLANN**

1. Use CMake and after click in "Configure", set the
   BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS and BUILD_MATLAB_BINDINGS to OFF.
2. Click again in "Configure", then "Generate".
3. Open the solucion file (with VS as administrator).
4. Edit the file flann\src\cpp\flann\util\serialization.h adding after the statement BASIC_TYPE_SERIALIZER(...) (it is aprox in line #93) the following lines:
   #ifdef _MSC_VER
   BASIC_TYPE_SERIALIZER(unsigned __int64);
   #endif
5. Build ALL_BUILD project and the INSTALL project, both in debug and release configuration.

**QHUll**

1. Open CMake and before clicking on "Configure", click on "Add Entry" and fill the fields as follows:
   Name  : CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX
   Type  : STRING
   Value : _d
2. Then click "Ok".
3. Click "Configure" twice and "Generate".
4. Open the solution and build ALL_BUILD project and the INSTALL project, both in debug and release configuration.

**VTK**

1. Open CMake and before clicking on "Configure", and if you didn't have the enviroment variables for Qt4.x manually locate:
   QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE to the location of qmake.exe 
   QT_QTCORE_librery_RELEASE 
   QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_DEBUG
   QT_MKSPECIF_DIR
2. Open the solution and build ALL_BUILD project and the INSTALL project, both in debug and release configuration.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep. I will let you know if this works

Comment: Works! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great! But you don't need visual studio in admin mode if you change the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX respectively to a folder with writing rights for your user.