# Understanding StereoMatching in Point Cloud Library

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library

**Situation**: I am trying to get `point cloud` with `pcl::AdaptiveCostSOStereoMatching`, which uses two rectified images (pics are ok).

**I used** these tutorials to learn how to do this:
[First tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/uploads/cglibs13_stereo.pdf)
[Second tutorial](https://github.com/kalectro/pcl_groovy/blob/master/stereo/tools/test_baseline.cpp)

**Error**: programm crashes in runtime when calling `"compute"` method of `AdaptiveCostSOStereoMatching`

**Question**: how to correctly pass images to `"compute"` method?

**I tried**:
1) Images converted by [png2pcd](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/tools/png2pcd.cpp)
(**command line:** `"png2pcd.exe in.png out.pcd"`)
2) Images converted with function below from `cv::Mat`
But no luck.

**Function which converts cv::Mat to pcl::PointCloud**

```cpp
void MatToPointCloud(Mat& mat, pcl::PointCloud<RGB>::Ptr cloud)
{
 int width = mat.cols;
 int height = mat.rows;
 pcl::RGB val;
 val.r = 0; val.g = 0; val.b = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++)
  {
   auto point = mat.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
   //std::cout << j << " " << i << "\n";
   val.b = point[0];
   val.g = point[1];
   val.r = point[2];
   cloud->at(j, i) = val;
  }
 }
```

**pcl::AdaptiveCostSOStereoMatching (compute)**

```cpp
    // Input
    Mat leftMat, rightMat;
    leftMat = imread("left.png");
    rightMat = imread("right.png");

    int width = leftMat.cols;
    int height = rightMat.rows;
    pcl::RGB val;
    val.r = 0; val.g = 0; val.b = 0;

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::RGB>::Ptr left_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::RGB>(width, height, val));
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::RGB>::Ptr right_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::RGB>(width, height, val));

    MatToPointCloud(leftMat, left_cloud);
    MatToPointCloud(rightMat, right_cloud);

    // Calculation
    pcl::AdaptiveCostSOStereoMatching stereo;
    stereo.setMaxDisparity(60);
    //stereo.setXOffest(0); Почему-то не распознается
    stereo.setRadius(5);
    stereo.setSmoothWeak(20);
    stereo.setSmoothStrong(100);
    stereo.setGammaC(25);
    stereo.setGammaS(10);
    stereo.setRatioFilter(20);
    stereo.setPeakFilter(0);
    stereo.setLeftRightCheck(true);
    stereo.setLeftRightCheckThreshold(1);
    stereo.setPreProcessing(true);

    stereo.compute(*left_cloud, *right_cloud); // <-- CRASHING THERE 
    stereo.medianFilter(4);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr out_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    stereo.getPointCloud(318.11220, 224.334900, 368.534700, 0.8387445, out_cloud, left_cloud);
```

**Error information:**
**Output log**: HEAP[App.exe]:
Heap block at 0000006B0F828460 modified at 0000006B0F8284A8 past requested size of 38
App.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

**left_cloud** (*a right cloud looks like left_cloud*)
[image]

**Mini question**: if `AdaptiveCostSOStereoMatching` really allows build point cloud from 2 images, how `ACSSM` doing this without insintric and excentic parameters?

Comment: could you add the actual error string please

Comment: I added error information. (Post updated)

Comment: in my experience with PCL the pointers are not so intuitive. `compute` takes pointers to a cloud, and you are using an inbuilt `Ptr`. a few suggestions to try: either drop the dereferencing (i.e. `left_cloud` not `*left_cloud`), pass it as a reference with and `&` instead of the `*`, or just use a straight point cloud not the `Ptr` and pass them as references with `&`

Comment: I did this, but error still there.
Also I have strange situation: when I turn off preProcessing (stereo.setPreProcessing(false)), programm not crashing, but output cloud is empty (after stereo.getPointCloud).

Comment: My PCL(`x64 VS2013`) pack did not contain `stereo` libruary.
I downloaded it manually from other PCL pack(`x64 VS2010`).
Could this be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: I downloaded and installed old version of PCL without `stereo`.
After that, I downloaded `stereo` from other PCL pack and add this library to my PCL pack. And it worked incorrectly.

**Solution**: I compilled `PCL 1.8` and my programm is ok now.
**OS**: `Windows`
**IDE**: `MSVS 12 2013 x64`

If you will try to compile PCL, these links can help you:
[Official-tutorial-1](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_dependencies_windows.php#compiling-pcl-dependencies-windows)
[Official-tutorial-2](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_windows.php#compiling-pcl-windows)
[Good help with FLANN and VTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782972/c-cmake-flann-failling-when-building-pcl-in-vs2012)

[Example to verify installation](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/examples/stereo/example_stereo_baseline.cpp)